# Expand/Collapse TreeView Nodes on Ctrl+LeftMouse in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview

I want to collapse or expand all TreeView nodes under parent node if user holds down Left Control key and presses left mouse button on expansion arrow of tree view.

How do you do this in WPF?  It's not as obvious as it was in WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that seems to work for me:

```
<TreeView TreeViewItem.Collapsed="TreeViewItem_Collapsed" TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded"/>
```

(The above is omitting things like `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplate` for brevity)

```
Private Sub TreeViewItem_Expanded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) Then DirectCast(e.OriginalSource, TreeViewItem).ExpandSubtree()
End Sub

Private Sub TreeViewItem_Collapsed(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) Then CollapseSubtree(e.OriginalSource)
End Sub

Private Sub CollapseSubtree(Item As TreeViewItem)
    Item.IsExpanded = False

    For Each Child In Item.ItemContainerGenerator.Items
        CollapseSubtree(Item.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(Child))
    Next
End Sub
```

## Explanation

Since [`TreeViewItem.Expanded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.expanded) and [`TreeViewItem.Collapsed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.collapsed) are both [routed events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview), we can handle them at the `TreeView` level as they "bubble" up. All items in the `TreeView` will trigger either `TreeViewItem_Collapsed` or `TreeViewItem_Expanded` when they close or open, respectively.

In my quick tests, `e.OriginalSource` always referred to the `TreeViewItem` that was expanded/collapsed, but some more rigorous testing might be in order.

In the event handlers, we use [`Keyboard.IsKeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown) to determine whether the left control key is currently being pressed. If so, we take the appropriate action.

For expansion, `TreeViewItem` already has a convenient [`ExpandSubtree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.expandsubtree) method, so we can just use that.

For whatever reason, there is no matching `CollapseSubtree` built in, so I made my own. At its heart, it's a simple recursive method that closes the node you give it and then runs itself again for all child nodes. The trick is in getting the child `TreeViewItem`s (containers), instead of the data objects they are representing. To do this, I make use of the `ItemContainerGenerator`, which is the class that each `TreeViewItem` uses to create its children.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and kindness to answer the question.  Really nicely and fully explained - it's helped me a lot.